# Why is my knockout module losing it's binding when receiving a PubNub message?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, pubnub

In a knockout module, I have an observable array that is iterated in the view using a foreach:

```
    <div id="data" data-bind="foreach: dataItems, visible: !loading()">
      <!-- ko compose: {model: $data} --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

I have a function to fill this observable array, this way:

```
    var dataItems = ko.observableArray();
    var getItems = function(isAMessage){
        dataItems([]);
        dataItems.push(new dataItem('1'));
        dataItems.push(new dataItem('2'));
        dataItems.push(new dataItem('3'));

        if (isAMessage) {
            dataItems.push(new dataItem('4'));
            dataItems.push(new dataItem('5'));
            dataItems.push(new dataItem('6'));
        }
    }
```

And in the activate funcion of the module, I'm subscribing to a pubnub channel, this way:

```
    var activate = function () {
        getItems(false);

        var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
            publish_key: 'pub-...',
            subscribe_key: 'sub-...'
        });

        pubnub.subscribe({
            channel: 'someChannel',
            message: function (m) {
                getItems(true);
            }
        });
    };
```

The thing is that when I receive a pubnub message, the function gets called but the observable array dataItems has no subscriptors, so, the view is not updated. When the function getItems is called from the activate function, dataItems has 2 subscriptors, but when it's called from the pubnub message callback, it has none. I don't know what am I doing wrong!!!

Comment: `dataItems has 2 subscriptors, but when it's called from the pubnub message callback, it has none` => how did you test this, are you sure the pubnub function fires at all? After subscribing to your PubNub channel, you still need to publish a message to it for your subscription callback to fire (from [the docs](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tutorials/publish-subscribe/)). Could you also include the constructor function/ object in which these functions are stored, that would help.

Comment: The observable array has a method named getSubscriptionsCount. I'm sure the message is received and the pubnub function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I wasn't injecting pubnub into the module.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in line 1 of your `getItems` method you are resetting the observableArray?

`dataItems([]);`

I'm not too familiar with KnockoutJS, but I think you can remove this function because it looks like everytime you are calling `getItems` you are resetting the array

Comment: That's the idea, every time I call the function, I want to reset the array, that's not the problem, since It works well when the function is called outside the pubnub callback.